# SFDX: Deploy Source to Org: Very slow

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I am using command:

```
SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

To deploy Apex code to a sandbox environment.

But often it is taking a very long time (multiple minutes) to respond/complete.

**QUESTION**

How can I get quicker feedback/response from Salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get quicker feedback/response from Salesforce?

You can't; it takes as long as it takes. The force:source:deploy command can't determine a minimal deployment package to generate, so it deploys **everything**. Making smaller packages and/or using 2GP (second generation packaging) would greatly improve performance.

Comment: Thanks. How would I enable second generation packaging in a Sandbox environment?

Comment: @Robs 2GP is enabled in your dev hub org. The packages would be installed to your sandbox for testing. Remember, DX is a source-driven tool, not an org-driven tool. It's a different way of doing development. You'd be developing in a scratch org as opposed to a sandbox. Sandboxes would be given more of a QA/UAT role than development in that scenario.

Comment: I've noticed that using Org-based development model (now available for SFDX) deploying a single class takes much more (>30s) in comparison to working with tools like MavenMate (<10s).

Comment: @jonathanwiesel force:source:deploy deploys everything. Normal development should still be using force:source:pull/force:source:push in a scratch org.You will get terrible performance if you try to deploy with this every time. It's literally no better than the metadata API for performance, but is available to help avoid the force:source:convert/force:mdapi:deploy cycle.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I think what Jonathan is referring to retrieving/deploying single file vs package.xml. I as seeing upwards of 40-50 seconds to push any changes. And about a minute to open default org.

Comment: @SalesforceArchitect That's odd. I usually get a response within a few seconds. I'm not sure what to say about that, except maybe check internet connection?

Comment: I am on corporate n/w, so internet speed is good. I also tried from home, same thing. And it is not just me, I noticed the lag for all the team members. Not sure what is going on :(

Comment: @sfdcfox you may want to update this answer.  You can definitely deploy individual files to sandboxes with force:source:deploy, at least as of v45.0.  I'm also frustrated by this, and I see that the actual deployment/load of the metadata is only taking 10-20 seconds, but that the deployment job/request can be stuck in PENDING status for SEVERAL minutes.  I hope SFDX starts offering the option to use the Tooling API rather than MD API for performance

Comment: @Bow-chicawow-ers I find some scratch orgs are just slow for no good reason (I'm sure there is a good reason in the black box that is Salesforce) and it's often faster to create a new one that struggle trying to push changes to a slow one.